# How can i excute a list of methods using either Action, Delegate or List?

Tags: c#, list, delegates, action

Let assume i have 3 methods with the same signature in the same class

```
Void Method1(string a, string b)
Void Method2(string a, string b)
Void Method3(string a, string b)
```

i want to call the method in this manner:

```
foreach(Item item in T)
(
  item(a,b);
)
```

What is the best way of doing it: Action, List, Delegate , etc ...

NB: i read about them but don't really know how to use it in this particular scenario

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to call the methods in the manner that you specified, do the following:

```
var methods = new List<Action<string, string>> { 
    Method1,
    Method2,
    Method3
};

foreach (var method in methods) {
    item(a, b);
)
```

Answer (score 2):

Assuming your actual methods actually do return void, you can use a [`MulticastDelegate`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.multicastdelegate%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

```
Action<string, string> action = Method1;
action += Method2; //promote delegate to Multicast Delegate
action += Method3;

action("x", "y");
```

If your methods return something else, and you do want to have access to all three return values, you shouldn't use a multicast delegate. E.g., if the methods returned an int, then `int i = action("x", "y");` would only capture the return value of the *last* method to be called.

In that case, you should call each method individually.

Note: Since you said "Action, Delegate or List", I feel it's important to point out that [`Action<T>`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/018hxwa8%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) *is* a delegate.

Answer (score 1):

you can use `Delegates` to call multiple methods having same signature.

Try This:

```
        public delegate void myDelegate(string a, string b);


        myDelegate delMethods = new myDelegate(method1);
        delMethods+=new myDelegate(method2);
        delMethods+= new myDelegate(method3);
        delMethods("a","b");
```

Answer (score 1):

You could write a helper method like so:

```
public static void Call<T1, T2>(T1 arg1, T2 arg2, params Action<T1, T2>[] actions)
{
    foreach (var action in actions)
        action(arg1, arg2);
}
```

Then you could use it like this:

```
using System;

namespace Demo
{
    internal class Program
    {
        private void run()
        {
            Call("a", "b", method1, method2, method3);

            // You can pass as many methods as you need:

            Call("a", "b", method1, method2, method3, method1, method2, method3);
        }

        public static void Call<T1, T2>(T1 arg1, T2 arg2, params Action<T1, T2>[] actions)
        {
            foreach (var action in actions)
                action(arg1, arg2);
        }

        private static void method1(string a, string b)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("method1(), a = " + a + ", b = " + b);
        }

        private static void method2(string a, string b)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("method2(), a = " + a + ", b = " + b);
        }

        private static void method3(string a, string b)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("method3(), a = " + a + ", b = " + b);
        }

        private static void Main()
        {
            new Program().run();
        }
    }
}
```

However, I'd probably just use the multicast delegate solution given by @dcastro.

Answer (score 0):

```
    public delegate void customDelegate(string a, string b);


    customDelegate methodsDelegate = new customDelegate(method1);
    methodsDelegate+=new customDelegate (method2);
    methodsDelegate+= new customDelegate (method3);
    methodsDelegate("a","b");
```

Whatever is the order of subscription same sequence your methods are invoked.

But before doing this you should read and understand delegates properly because its quite achievable without putting this question on StackOverFlow.